# Why is my game not failing if the same card is clicked twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[UI pic of game. Instrument pic/cards that can be clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl5n8.png)The game is built on not clicking the same card twice. If you do, you lose the game. The problem is it will just cycle through the cards and not fail when the same card is clicked.

The game is not supposed to fail until the same card is clicked twice. And an alert pops up if you lose.
I did use a .find in the clickCount function but getting a "Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function." Instead, I used a .forEach. Thank you for your help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import InstruCard from "./components/InstruCard/InstruCard"
import Wrapper from "./components/Wrapper/Wrapper"
import instruments from "./instruments.json"
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    instruments,
    score: 0,
    topScore: 0
  }

  gameOver = () => {
    if (this.state.score > this.state.topScore) {
      this.setState({ topScore: this.state.score }, function () {
      });
    }
    this.state.instruments.forEach(instrument => {
      instrument.count = 0;
    });
    alert(`Game Over! \nscore: ${this.state.score}`);
    this.setState({ score: 0 });
    return true;
  }

  clickCount = (id) => {
    var temp = [...this.state.instruments]
    temp.forEach((instrument) => {
      if (instrument.id === instrument) {
        if (instrument.count === 0) {
          instrument.count += 1;
          this.setState({ score: this.state.score + 1 });
        } else {
          this.gameOver();
        }
      }
    });
    temp.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
    this.setState({ instruments: temp })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Navbar score={this.state.score} topScore={this.state.topScore}>Clicky Game</Navbar>
        {this.state.instruments.map(instrument => (
          <InstruCard
            clickCount={this.clickCount}
            id={instrument.id}
            key={instrument.id}
            image={instrument.image}
          />
        ))}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
import "./card.css";

const InstruCard = props => (
    <div className="card" onClick={() => props.clickCount(props.id)}>
        <div className="img-container">
            <img src={props.image} alt={props.name} />
        </div>
    </div>
);

export default InstruCard;
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to provide some more context? The premise of your game isn't clear. Maybe provide a screenshot of the UI. The more information you give, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you. I did an a pic and did edit some info about the game.

Comment: Cool that helps. In click count you use `this.state.instruments.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)`. You can't update the state this way, instead you should do `this.setState({instruments: this.state.instruments.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5) )}`. Also, can you include the code for you `InstruCard` component?

Comment: Yes. I just updated the InstruCard to here.

Comment: the setState you recommended did not change anything in the game. Still "loses" after the first card is clicked.

Comment: Thank you. It does cycle through now but its not calling the gameOver(). Like if you click the same card more than once.

Comment: Ok I have no idea why it wouldn't call `gameOver()`. Make sure you aren't getting any errors. I included a `console.log(e)` in my answer that I've now removed, make sure that you got rid of that too. If things continue not to work, update the code snippets in your question with your changes.

Comment: Yeah. I logged 'id' instead of e but removed it. Updated everything. Trying to see if the call is placed wrong but seems to not be.

Comment: I forgot to tell you I did solve it. 
(Instrument.id === id) and not instrument.

Comment: Ahh, I can't believe I missed that! I updated it in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in `clickCount()` you are referencing `instruments`, which you import from `instruments.json` instead of `this.state.instruments`. This means when you then sort, you are sorting the version stored in `state` but `instruments` remains the same. This results in the counts and the instruments not aligning.

Here is how `clickCount()` should look...

```
clickCount = (id) => {
    var temp = [...this.state.instruments]

    temp.forEach((instrument) => {
        if (instrument.id === id) {
            if (instrument.count === 0) {
                instrument.count += 1;
                this.setState({ score: this.state.score + 1 });
            } else {
                this.gameOver();
            }
        }
    })

    temp.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
    this.setState( {instruments: temp} )
}
```

Hope that helps, let me know if I missed something.